# How to charge the customer using previous payment card details in paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

How to charge the customer using previously paid card details in Paypal

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Except for recurring payments, customer's funding source is auto-selected by PayPal system by default or manually selected by customer during the checkout process. Merchant/Receiver cannot force define the funding source.